# Как определить победителя в крестиках-ноликах?

Tags: java

Игра в крестики-нолики происходит на поле, представляющим собой массив `char[][]`:

```
{{-, O, -}
{X, O, X}
{-, -, X}}
```

Каким образом я могу определить победителя, т.е. чтобы несколько ячеек подряд содержали один и тот же символ?

Comment: пасибо за минусы, за что хоть :\\

Comment: Вы перечислили четыре примера. А всего выигрышных комбинаций восемь. Минусы, видимо, за то что вы не додумали вопрос прежде чем его задавать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С большим трудом понял ваш вопрос. Формулируйте лучше.

То есть у вас есть игровое поле, которое выражено матрицей char'ов, в ячейках которой может быть `X`, `O` и, видимо, какой-то ещё дефолтный символ, допустим это тире:

```
{{-, O, -}
{-, X, X}
{-, O, X}}
```

Проверить наличие X или O очень просто. Вам нужен перебор матрицы:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gameField.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < gameField[i].length; j++) {
        // а теперь проверяете, что содержится в ячейке gameField[i][j]
    }
}
```

Но вам, видимо, нужно условие выигрыша. Для этого поступите следующим образом. Я не буду писать за вас код, но опишу общий принцип. Значит, делайте перебор в двойном цикле, который я привёл выше. Как только вы наткнётесь на символ `X` или `O`, то проверьте соседние ячейки на наличие того же символа. И если там тоже есть этот символ, то проверьте и следующую ячейку. Следите только за тем, чтобы не выйти за границу диапазона массива, иначе получите ошибку. Нашли три подряд - победитель найден. В коде это примерно вот так:

```
   if (gameField[i][j] == 'X') {
        if (gameField[i][j + 1] == 'X') {
            if (gameField[i][j + 2] == 'X') {
                System.out.println("Ура, победитель - X!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Только я вам тут проверку в одну сторону показал, а вам надо проверки во все стороны реализовать. Плюс реализовать проверку на длину массива, чтобы случайно не выйти за его пределы.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] map = {
                {'X','O','X'},
                {'O','X','O'},
                {'X',' ',' '},
        };
        
        // Горизонталь
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                sum += map[x][y];
            }
            win(sum);
        }
        // Вертикаль
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
                sum += map[x][y];
            }
            win(sum);
        }
        // Диагонали
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            sum += map[i][i];
        }
        win(sum);
        sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            sum += map[i][2-i];
        }
        win(sum);
    }


    private final static int maxX = 'X'*3;
    private final static int maxO = 'O'*3;

    private static void win(int sum) {
        if(sum == maxX)
            System.out.println("Победил X");
        if(sum == maxO)
            System.out.println("Победил O");
    }
```